# Error trying to pass data between activities

Tags: android, email, android-activity

This is what I have:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;

    public class FireScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.firescreen);


    EditText FIinvolvedtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FIinvolvedtext);
     String fireinvolvedsave = FIinvolvedtext.getText().toString();

        View FIUnitsStart = findViewById(R.id.FIUnitsStart);
        FIUnitsStart.setOnClickListener(this);
        View FIMainResume = findViewById(R.id.FIMainResume);
        FIMainResume.setOnClickListener(this);

        Spinner fire_type_spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.FItypespin);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> 
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.typespin_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        fire_type_spin.setAdapter(adapter);

        Spinner fire_type_array = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.FIareaspin);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> 
        adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.areaspin_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        fire_type_array.setAdapter(adapter1);

        Spinner action_type_spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.FIactionspin);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> 
        adapter11 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.actionspin_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter11.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        action_type_spin.setAdapter(adapter11);}


        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.FIUnitsStart:
                Intent UnitScreen = new Intent(this, UnitScreen.class);
                UnitScreen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                startActivity(UnitScreen);
            break;

            case R.id.FIMainResume:
                Intent Main = new Intent(this, Main.class);
                Main.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                startActivity(Main);
            break;

            Intent pass = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);   
            String keyIdentifer  = null;
            pass.putExtra("Involved", fireinvolvedsave);
    // Getting an error here: fireinvolvedsave cannot be resolved to a variable
            startActivity(pass);}}}
```

help -- I have 7 activities of data I need to pass back to the main activity so I can place them into an email --- kinda stuck right here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fireinvolvedsave can't be seen because you declared it as a local variable a different method to the one you are reading it in; you need to declare it as a field of the activity using, eg, `public String` etc, after `public class FireScreen ... {`

---

```
public class FireScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
  private String fireinvolvedsave;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.firescreen);

    EditText FIinvolvedtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FIinvolvedtext);
    fireinvolvedsave = FIinvolvedtext.getText().toString();

    // rest of original code for onCreate goes here
  }


  public void onClick(View v)
  {
    // original code etc

    Intent pass = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);   

    // this now has a value:
    pass.putExtra("Involved", fireinvolvedsave);
    startActivity(pass);
  }
}
```

---

Try something like

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent();
String strText = myIntent.getStringExtra("Involved");
```

and then

```
emailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, strText);
```

Comment: I dont understand your comment im sorry im new to this

Comment: Intent pass = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class); still shows error : "Unreachable code"

Comment: You need a `case default:` above it and a `break;` below it.

Comment: Great, this has worked without errors . . . now on the Main.class activity . . . how do I get the data from that into the Extra_Text of the email intent i have there

Comment: You need to get the intent that called the activity using `getIntent()`, get the extra from it using the name you used to pass it in -- in this case `getExtra("Involved")` -- and `putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, String)` in your email intent to pass it on.  (Code added.)

Comment: @Ben Williams using that I get an error: The method getExtra(String) is undefined for the type Intent

Comment: Sorry, getStringExtra.  See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
final String fireinvolvedsave = FIinvolvedtext.getText().toString();
```

See if that works.

EDIT: so got confused by your formatting. The core issue is that you are using a method-local variable in an instance function. You need to make it an instance variable of the entire Activity. Your `onCreate` would now look like this:

```
String fireinvolvedsave;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.firescreen);


    EditText FIinvolvedtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FIinvolvedtext);
    fireinvolvedsave = FIinvolvedtext.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways you can do this. e.g. you could make fireinvolvedsave an instance variable as Ben suggested.

However, since you seem to be using it only in your onClick() method, here is the simplest way. Move these lines from onCreate() to onClick():

```
EditText FIinvolvedtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FIinvolvedtext);
String fireinvolvedsave = FIinvolvedtext.getText().toString();
```

Comment: i have done that and now the entire Intent pass line has an error that says unreachable code

Answer (score 0):

```
just try this
public class FireScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
String fireinvolvedsave ;
EditText FIinvolvedtext;
View FIUnitsStart,FIMainResume;
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.firescreen);

FIinvolvedtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FIinvolvedtext);
fireinvolvedsave = FIinvolvedtext.getText().toString();

        FIUnitsStart = findViewById(R.id.FIUnitsStart);
        FIUnitsStart.setOnClickListener(this);
        FIMainResume = findViewById(R.id.FIMainResume);
        FIMainResume.setOnClickListener(this);

       Spinner fire_type_spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.FItypespin);
       ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> 
       adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.typespin_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       fire_type_spin.setAdapter(adapter);

       Spinner fire_type_array = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.FIareaspin);
       ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> 
       adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.areaspin_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       fire_type_array.setAdapter(adapter1);

       Spinner action_type_spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.FIactionspin);
       ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> 
       adapter11 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.actionspin_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       adapter11.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       action_type_spin.setAdapter(adapter11);
 }

    public void onClick(View v) 
{
            switch(v.getId())
    {
                case R.id.FIUnitsStart: Intent UnitScreen = new Intent(this, UnitScreen.class);
                          UnitScreen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                          startActivity(UnitScreen);
                          break;

               case R.id.FIMainResume:Intent Main = new Intent(this, Main.class);
                             Main.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                             startActivity(Main);
                             break;

               default:         Intent pass = new Intent(FireScreen.this, Main.class);   
                    pass.putExtra("Involved", fireinvolvedsave);
                    startActivity(pass);
    }
}
```

}